# Macbook won't output to TV via HDMI in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, display, hdmi, external-display, hdcp

I'm trying to use my TV as a monitor for my Macbook running a fresh install of Windows 10 via bootcamp, but all I'm getting is a solid green screen.

I've tried a few different HDMI cables and I'm getting the same issue with all of them, yet the cables work fine with OS X... which leads me to believe it's some kind of software/driver/HDCP related issue within Windows 10. The NVIDIA Control Panel seems to be recognizing my TV just fine though.

Any ideas?